# How to make UserControl set value of another Form txtBox, labels

Tags: c#, winforms

How to make this using C# WinForm?

Is there any example?

Comment: You might want to elaborate on your question a little. Since some people might need a refresher or some extra information on your question.

Comment: Make the UserControl raise a custom EVENT.  The other form will then need to subscribe to that event and do something when it is received.  How will that other form get a reference to the UserControl, though, if it is on a different form?  You need to describe how these two forms interact, and tell us which form creates which one, as well as which form contains the UserControl.